# Building a batch to read info from txt and decide what to do with a video file

Tags: batch-processing, batch-file

THIRD DAY!

New output file txt:

```
Filename          : %FILENAME%.%EXTENSION%
Sizes             : 1.66 GiB for 1h 58mn 0s 615ms at 2 014 Kbps
Writing_App       : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2542/release)

Video_#0          : DivX 5 MPEG-4 Visual at 1 812 Kbps, with 1.49 GiB (90%)
Aspect            : 704 x 368 (1.913) at 23.976 fps
Writing_App_V     : DivX 6.8.5 (UTC 2009-08-20)

Audio_#0          : AC3
Mode_#0           : Constant
Sample_#0         : 48000
Channels_#0       : 2
Size_#0           : 162 MiB (10%)
Title_#0          : 

Audio_#1          : MP3
Mode_#1           : Constant
Sample_#1         : 44100
Channels_#1       : 2
Size_#1           : 101 MiB (11%)
Title_#1          :
```

---

```
rem Required to use Delayed !Variable! Expansion
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Create all text files (copied from your example)
rem for %%T in ("*.avi") do "C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\MediaInfo.exe" --output=file://"C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\luis4.csv" --logfile="%%~nT.cod" "%%T"
rem echo.>TXTCollector.lst
rem for %%Z in ("*.cod") do type "%%~Z">>TXTCollector.lst && echo ===========================================>>TXTCollector.lst && echo.>>TXTCollector.lst
rem ren TXTCollector.lst TXTCollector.txt
rem Process each file
for %%F in (*.cod) do (
   rem Delete variables that may not exist in certain files
   set Audio_#1=
   rem Read variables from this text file (explained above)
   for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%%F") do (
      for %%c in (%%a) do set %%c=%%b
      set %%c=!%%c:~1!
   )
   ECHO VirtualDub.Open("r:\\%%~nF.avi","",0);>"%%~nF.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.RemoveInputStreams();>>"%%~nF.vcf"
)
```

Writed all the bat file and started to debug. My first two lines started a problem. This batch is to create a script file (.vcf) and the Redirection with >> is not working anymore.
ECHO VirtualDub.Open("r:\%%~nF.avi","",0);>"%%~nF.vcf"
Created a file with the name correct with the parameter %%~nF.vcf but flushed inside the file all the work done by
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%%F")
ECHO VirtualDub.RemoveInputStreams();>>"%%~nF.vcf" generated a file called %~nF.vcf (this means that the parameter doesnt work anymore.)
Tried to switch off EnableDelayedExpansion, same results. Maybe its because the brackets.
Stuck Again!

---

SECOND DAY!

OK, @Aacini, thanks... Will try to resume...
I Have a lot of files to work with... I generate a .txt for every file. I'm trying to do a batch that reads each .txt and decides what to do with the original file.

TXT FILES:

```
General
ORIGINAL_FILENAME.avi
818 MiB for 1h 46mn 25s 14ms
AVI-Mux GUI 1.16.11, Dec 15 2004  14:51:34

Video #0
XviD MPEG-4 Visual, with 624 MiB (76%),  at 23.976 fps
XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio #0
MPEG Audio Version 1 Layer 3
Variable
44.1 KHz
2 channels
85.8 MiB (10%)
Portuguese BR - 3LT0N
LAME3.93a

Audio #1
MPEG Audio Version 1 Layer 3
Variable
48.0 KHz
2 channels
97.5 MiB (12%)
English - 3LT0N
LAME3.98r
```

---

The batch i've been thinking so far...

```
IF DOESNT EXIST "Audio #1" in TXT goto :ONEAUDIO
IF EXIST "AC-3" in TXT goto :AC3

Set Value 0 from txt line 02 = filename

"for audio 1"
Set Value 1 from txt line 12 = Variable OR Constant
Set Value 2 from txt line 13 = 44.1 OR 48.0

"for audio 2"
Set Value 3 from txt line 21 = Variable or Constant
Set Value 4 from txt line 22 = 44.1 or 48.0

if value 1 = variable goto :variable1 ELSE goto :constant1

:variable1
(will execute some commands here)
if value 2 = 44.1 goto :22 ELSE goto :24

:22
(will execute some commands here)
goto :jump24

:24
(will execute some commands here)

:jump24
if value 3 = variable goto :variable2 ELSE goto :constant2

:variable2
(will execute some commands here)
if value 4 = 44.1 goto :44 ELSE goto :48

:44
(will execute some commands here)
goto :end

:48
(will execute some commands here)
goto :end

:constant1
(will execute some commands here)
goto :end

:constant2
(will execute some commands here)
goto :end


:ONEAUDIO
later
goto :end

:AC3
later
goto :end

:end
```

This will run in some trouble... I only know something about FOR (LOOP) and as far as I know it can not work with GOTO :EXAMPLE. Maybe work using two batch files... a loop for calling the second batch parsing the filename.txt

Another way I was thinking is the batch generate a "batch model" for every videofile, then read the .txt for the videofile, then replacing strings in the "batch model". But this is too advanced for me.

---

FIRST DAY:

I need help to join my batch files into just one and add the ability to this batch to read a file .txt and decide the next steps for a bunch of videos in the same dir. It's all about of converting audio from avi to generate compatibility to editing programs...

The steps are:

1) Generate a .txt for every video file with the basic info about the video and audio.

```
for %%a in ("*.avi") do "C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\MediaInfo.exe" --output=file://"C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\luis.csv" --logfile="%%~na.txt" "%%a"
```

or generate a large file with all the small ones:

```
for %%a in ("*.avi") do "C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\MediaInfo.exe" --output=file://"C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\luis.csv" --logfile="%%~na.txt" "%%a"
echo.>TXTCollector.lst
for %%i in ("*.txt") do type "%%~i">>TXTCollector.lst && echo ===========================================>>TXTCollector.lst && echo.>>TXTCollector.lst && del "%%~i"
ren TXTCollector.lst TXTCollector.txt
```

OUTPUT FILE EXAMPLE:

```
General           : ORIGINAL NAME FOR THE VIDEO FILES.avi
Format            : 820 MiB for 1h 26mn 38s 777ms at 1 324 Kbps
Writing App.      : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)

Video #0          : XviD MPEG-4 Visual at 925 Kbps, with 574 MiB (70%)
Aspect            : 608 x 336 (16:9) at 23.976 fps
Writing App.      : XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio #0          : 119 MiB (15%), AC-3  ,  
Infos             : Constant at 192 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 1 channel
Writing App.      : , 

Audio #1          : 110 MiB (12%), MPEG Audio Version 1 Layer 3,  
Infos             : Constant at 128 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 2 channels
Writing App.      : LAME3.97 , -m j -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 17 -b 128
```

---

2) From there, reading the audio formats from files, I move the files to the specific folder and execute the batch in that folder to run the conversion.

Example to the bats.

```
REM @echo off
:: create the virtual drives and go to the root of drive r:
set ORIGINALDIR=%~d0
subst r: "%cd%"
md JobDone
subst s: "%cd%\JobDone"
r:
cd\
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.Open("r:\\%%~w","",0);>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.RemoveInputStreams();>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetSource(0x73647561,0,1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].DeleteComments(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AddComment(0x00000003,"","Portuguese");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
REM for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AddComment(0x00000003,"","English");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AdjustChapters(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetMode(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetInterleave(1,500,1,0,0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetClipMode(1,1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetConversion(0,0,0,0,0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetVolume();>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetCompression(85,48000,2,0,16000,1,12,"AQAEAAAAgAEBAAAA");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].EnableFilterGraph(0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Clear();>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetSource(0x73647561,1,1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].DeleteComments(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AddComment(0x00000003,"","English");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
REM for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AddComment(0x00000003,"","Portuguese");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AdjustChapters(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetMode(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetInterleave(1,500,1,0,0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetClipMode(1,1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetConversion(0,0,0,0,0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetVolume();>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetCompression(85,48000,2,0,16000,1,12,"AQAEAAAAgAEBAAAA");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].EnableFilterGraph(0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Clear();>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.DeleteComments(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.AddComment(0x00000002,"ISFT","VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2542/release)");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.AdjustChapters(1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetDepth(24,24);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetMode(0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetFrameRate(0,1);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetIVTC(0,0,-1,0);>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetCompression();>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.video.filters.Clear();>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.SaveAVI("s:\\%%~nw.avi");>>"%%~nw.vcf"
for %%w in ("*.avi") do ECHO VirtualDub.Close();>>"%%~nw.vcf"

:: Execute the script file just created
for %%a in ("*.vcf") do "C:\VirtualDubMod\VirtualDubMod.exe" /r /s"%%~fa" /x && del "%%~fa"

:: go back to previous folder and delete the virtual drives.
%ORIGINALDIR%
REM %~d0
subst r: /d
subst s: /d

:end
```

I have a folder and a batch for each job. Basically it's 3 different process:
Video files with AC3 audio needs a different approach...
Video files with MP3 converting everything to a constant bitrate and 48000 sampling rate.
Video files with already constante bitrate don't need converting but just a remux.

```
ONE AUDIO
+AC3 AUDIO
--2 CHANNELS
--6 CHANNELS
+MP3 AUDIO
--44100 SAMPLING RATE
--48000 SAMPLING RATE
+JUST REMUX AUDIO

TWO AUDIOS
+AC3
--2ch-2ch
--2ch-6ch
--6ch-2ch
--6ch-6ch
+1ST AUDIO ONLY
--44100
--48000
+2ND AUDIO ONLY
--44100
--48000
+44100-44100
+44100-48000
+48000-41000
+48000-48000
+INVERT AUDIO (just change the order of the audio tracks, no converting)
+JUST REMUX
```

---

This Is Where The Fun Begins:

Video files with just one audio is rare... can stay out of the batch.
If... there was one bat file to do it all... then the LOOP for (*.avi) will not work anymore, because every video file has it's own properties... then again... the batch will have to create the script (or a new bat to create the script) based on the filename.

```
Audio #0          : 119 MiB (15%), AC-3  ,  
Infos             : Constant at 192 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 1 channel
Writing App.      : ,
```

Just thinking about... if it was just one audio... then:
has ac3 (has 2ch do 2 channel conversion; if not do 6 channel conversion)
if not ac3 (has constant -> just remux -> else (if 48.0 do 48.0 conversion; else do 41000 conversion)

It's "quite simple"
But the files have two audios.... now it's very difficult to me.

```
Audio #0          : 119 MiB (15%), AC-3  ,  
Infos             : Constant at 192 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 1 channel
Writing App.      : , 

Audio #1          : 110 MiB (12%), MPEG Audio Version 1 Layer 3,  
Infos             : Constant at 128 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 2 channels
Writing App.      : LAME3.97 , -m j -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 17 -b 128
```

---

Let me explain somethings:
"Just remux" and "MP3s conversions" use the internal audio from video file. "AC3 conversion" is not that simple. Must pull out the audio from file, do the 1st conversion with other app, then do the second conversion in the original program.

```
md audio1
for %%x in ("*.avi") do "C:\VirtualDubMod\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%x" -vn -map 0:1 -acodec copy "%%~dpxaudio1\%%~nx.audio1.ac3"

md audio2
for %%u in ("*.avi") do "C:\VirtualDubMod\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%u" -vn -map 0:2 -acodec copy "%%~dpuaudio2\%%~nu.audio2.ac3"

cd audio1
for %%y in ("*.ac3") do "c:\Meus Programas\AUDIO\BeSweet\BeSweet.exe" -core( -input "%%~fy" -output "%%~dpy%%~ny.wav" -2ch ) -azid( -c light ) -ota( -hybridgain ) && del "%%~y"

cd..
cd audio2
for %%y in ("*.ac3") do "c:\Meus Programas\AUDIO\BeSweet\BeSweet.exe" -core( -input "%%~fy" -output "%%~dpy%%~ny.wav" -2ch ) -azid( -c light -L -3db ) -ota( -hybridgain ) && del "%%~y"
```

The script generated for the conversion can be broken into pieces:
1) video file to be processed 
2) 1st audio and options to convession
obs: mp3 (don't need to specify a file, it's a code for internal audio) AC3 (have to specify the .wav filename)
3) 2nd audio and options to conversion
4) video and options to conversion
5) filename to save new file
6) command to close the app at the end of process.

The batch can create a script (or a new batch to generate the script) pasting these peaces one by one. and the batch can have a "catalogue" of pieces and choose the right one by the info about the audio....

It's this possible?

Comment: You should try to reduce your question to the RELEVANT part. Nobody wants to read a book first.

Comment: @Paoli: Excuse me. I don't know about audio, codecs, video, etc., but I do know about Batch files. If you want our help try to state your problem in terms of text files, lines, strings, etc. i.e.: "If the text file have a line with string1, but not with string2, do process1, but if the file also include this_line, do another thing"...

Comment: @Aacini: thanks... I added some new info in the beginning. I Can't resume more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I will *try* to get something clear from all this mess...

You show us two different formats for the text file. The first one (under OUTPUT FILE EXAMPLE) is easier to process. I suppose that you may modify this file so the headings of each line be unique and have not spaces by inserting underscores or numbers (to be valid Batch variable names). This is your example file in the format required by my program:

```
General           : ORIGINAL NAME FOR THE VIDEO FILES.avi
Format            : 820 MiB for 1h 26mn 38s 777ms at 1 324 Kbps
Writing_App       : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)

Video_#0          : XviD MPEG-4 Visual at 925 Kbps, with 574 MiB (70%)
Aspect            : 608 x 336 (16:9) at 23.976 fps
Writing_App_V0    : XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio_#0          : 119 MiB (15%), AC-3  ,  
Infos_A0          : Constant at 192 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 1 channel
Writing_App_A0    : , 

Audio_#1          : 110 MiB (12%), MPEG Audio Version 1 Layer 3,  
Infos_A1          : Constant at 128 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 2 channels
Writing_App_A1    : LAME3.97 , -m j -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 17 -b 128
```

The following code will read previous file and define the variables of the left side of the colon with the values of the right side:

```
rem Read each line from the text file
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (thefile.txt) do (
   rem Eliminate spaces from variable name
   for %%c in (%%a) do set %%c=%%b
   rem Eliminate first character (space) from variable value
   set %%c=!%%c:~1!
)
```

After previous loop ends you may directly get the vale of each variable. For example, **ECHO !Format!** or **IF NOT DEFINED Audio_#1 ECHO One Audio** or **IF "!Audio_#0:AC-3=!" EQU "!Audio_#0!" ECHO Audio #0 is NOT AC-3"**, etc.

This is a first attempt to put all pieces together:

```
@echo off
rem Required to use Delayed !Variable! Expansion
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Create all text files (copied from your example)
for %%a in ("*.avi") do "C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\MediaInfo.exe" --output=file://"C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\luis.csv" --logfile="%%~na.txt" "%%a"
rem Process each file
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
   rem Delete variables that may not exist in certain files
   set Audio_#1=
   rem Read variables from this text file (explained above)
   for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%%f") do (
      for %%c in (%%a) do set %%c=%%b
      set %%c=!%%c:~1!
   )
   rem Identify each case
   set AC-3=NO
   if "!Audio_#0:AC-3=!" neq "!Audio_#0!" set AC-3=YES
   if not defined Audio_#1 (
      rem One Audio
      if !AC-3! equ YES (
         rem Process One Audio with AC-3
      ) else (
         rem Process One Audio with no AC-3
      )
   ) else (
      rem Two Audios
      if "!Audio_#1:AC-3=!" neq "!Audio_#1!" set AC-3=YES
      if !AC-3! equ YES (
         rem Process Two Audios with AC-3
      ) else (
         rem Process Two Audios with no AC-3
      )
   )
)
```

Try to understand this code and do several tests, then post your new questions.

Antonio

***ADDENDUM*:** Explanation on "Eliminate spaces from variable name"

If this FOR command:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (thefile.txt) do (
   set %%a=%%b
)
```

read this line:

```
General           : ORIGINAL NAME FOR THE VIDEO FILES.avi
```

then the executed SET command is this:

```
   set General           = ORIGINAL NAME FOR THE VIDEO FILES.avi
```

This way, the variable name is precisely "General<11 spaces>", so

```
echo %General%               does NOT work
echo %General           %    OK
```

To avoid this mess, spaces from variable name must be deleted.

You must know that if you execute this command:

```
for %%a in (    one        two         threee      ) do echo "%%a"
```

the result is:

```
"one"
"two"
"three"
```

So a FOR command may be used to eliminate spaces. OK?

Comment: Thanks for your time and help! I Have answered the question with the "final" batch. I Have learned some very interesting things in the last days. The only thing I don't understand in your code and don't found nothing in google... is the "delete leading space" in variables. That didn't work, and by luck and some thinking I was able to fix. If you know some page with info about changing values from variables, please let me know.

Comment: @Paoli: Please note that it refers to eliminate spaces from variable NAME! See the Addendum in my answer... BTW, may I ask you to select my answer as Useful? This give me 10 more points! Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for your new explanation. I was talking about something else. Lets see.

Comment: You put: "for %%c in (%%a) do set %%c=%%b" and "set %%c=!%%c:~1!" and that didn't work, don't deleted leading space. Thinking I was able to fix by "if I want to fix all '%%c's I need a 'for'. So I changed to: "for %%c in (%%a) do (" "set %%c=%%b" "set %%c=!%%c:~1!" ")". I was looking for explanation on google about "set %%c=!%%c:~1!" but found nothing in SET commands for example. I think it's a set of functions to change the data stored on variables. BTW, I set useful, but voting i get "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 0):

The batch is working, and tested against all kind of files. Thanks for all the help. This batch is doing what was intended for, but it has some work to do. It can be cleaned a lot. Later...

```
@echo off
rem create the virtual drives needed to VirtualDubMod work
set ORIGINALDRIVE=%~d0
subst r: "%cd%"
md JobDone
subst s: "%cd%\JobDone"
r:
cd\
rem Required to use Delayed !Variable! Expansion
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Create all text files (copied from your example)
for %%T in ("*.avi") do "C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\MediaInfo.exe" --output=file://"C:\Meus Programas\MEDIA\MediaInfo CLI\luis4.csv" --logfile="%%~nT.cod" "%%T"
rem Create "catalogue" from all INFOs created.
echo.>TXTCollector.lst
for %%Z in ("*.cod") do type "%%~Z">>TXTCollector.lst && echo ===========================================>>TXTCollector.lst && echo.>>TXTCollector.lst
ren TXTCollector.lst TXTCollector.txt
rem Process each file
for %%F in (*.cod) do (
   rem Setting the variables needed!
   set NAMEFILE=%%~nF
   rem Delete variables that may not exist in certain files
   set Audio_#1=
   rem Read variables from this text file (explained above)
   for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("%%F") do (
      rem Eliminate spaces from variable name?????????
      for %%c in (%%a) do (
         set %%c=%%b
         rem Eliminate first character (space) from variable value
         set %%c=!%%c:~1!
      )
   )
   ECHO VirtualDub.Open^("r:\\!NAMEFILE!.avi","",0^);>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.RemoveInputStreams^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   rem PROCESS FIRST AUDIO
   if !Audio_#0! equ AC3 (
      rem PROCESS AC3
      if !Channels_#0! equ 6 (
         rem Process AC3 6 Channels
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         ECHO AC3_1 HAS 6 CHANNELS
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         "C:\VirtualDubMod\ffmpeg.exe" -i "!NAMEFILE!.avi" -vn -map 0:1 -acodec copy "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.ac3"
         "c:\Meus Programas\AUDIO\BeSweet\BeSweet.exe" -core^( -input "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.ac3" -output "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.wav" -2ch ^) -azid^( -c light -L -3db ^) -ota^( -hybridgain ^)
         del "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.ac3"
      ) else (
         rem Process AC3 2 or 1 Channels
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         ECHO AC3_1 HAS 2 CHANNELS
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         "C:\VirtualDubMod\ffmpeg.exe" -i "!NAMEFILE!.avi" -vn -map 0:1 -acodec copy "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.ac3"
         "c:\Meus Programas\AUDIO\BeSweet\BeSweet.exe" -core^( -input "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.ac3" -output "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.wav" -2ch ^) -azid^( -c light ^) -ota^( -hybridgain ^)
         del "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.ac3"
      )
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetSource^("r:\\!NAMEFILE!.audio1.wav",0x00000201^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].DeleteComments^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AddComment^(0x00000003,"","Portuguese"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AdjustChapters^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetMode^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetInterleave^(1,500,1,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetClipMode^(1,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetConversion^(0,0,0,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetVolume^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetCompression^(85,48000,2,0,16000,1,12,"AQAEAAAAgAEBAAAA"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].EnableFilterGraph^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ) else (
      rem PROCESS MP3
      if !Mode_#0! equ Constant (
         rem JUST REMUX AUDIO
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetSource^(0x73647561,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].DeleteComments^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AddComment^(0x00000003,"","Portuguese"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AdjustChapters^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetMode^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetInterleave^(1,500,1,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetClipMode^(1,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetConversion^(0,0,0,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetVolume^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetCompression^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].EnableFilterGraph^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ) else (
         rem REDO AUDIO
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetSource^(0x73647561,0,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].DeleteComments^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AddComment^(0x00000003,"","Portuguese"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].AdjustChapters^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetMode^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetInterleave^(1,500,1,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetClipMode^(1,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetConversion^(0,0,0,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetVolume^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].SetCompression^(85,48000,2,0,16000,1,12,"AQAEAAAAgAEBAAAA"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         if !Sample_#0! equ 44100 (
            rem REDO 44100 AUDIO
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].EnableFilterGraph^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Add^("input"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Add^("resample"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Connect^(0, 0, 1, 0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.instance[1].SetInt^(0, 48000^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.instance[1].SetInt^(1, 64^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Add^("output"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Connect^(1, 0, 2, 0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ) else (
            rem REDO 48000 AUDIO
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].EnableFilterGraph^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[0].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         )
      )
   )
   rem PROCESS SECOND AUDIO
   if !Audio_#1! equ AC3 (
      rem PROCESS AC3
      if !Channels_#1! equ 6 (
         rem Process AC3 6 Channels
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         ECHO AC3_2 HAS 6 CHANNELS
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         "C:\VirtualDubMod\ffmpeg.exe" -i "!NAMEFILE!.avi" -vn -map 0:1 -acodec copy "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.ac3"
         "c:\Meus Programas\AUDIO\BeSweet\BeSweet.exe" -core^( -input "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.ac3" -output "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.wav" -2ch ^) -azid^( -c light -L -3db ^) -ota^( -hybridgain ^)
         del "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.ac3"
      ) else (
         rem Process AC3 2 or 1 Channels
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         ECHO AC3_2 HAS 2 CHANNELS
         ECHO -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
         "C:\VirtualDubMod\ffmpeg.exe" -i "!NAMEFILE!.avi" -vn -map 0:2 -acodec copy "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.ac3"
         "c:\Meus Programas\AUDIO\BeSweet\BeSweet.exe" -core^( -input "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.ac3" -output "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.wav" -2ch ^) -azid^( -c light ^) -ota^( -hybridgain ^)
         del "r:\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.ac3"
      )
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetSource^("r:\\!NAMEFILE!.audio2.wav",0x00000201^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].DeleteComments^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AddComment^(0x00000003,"","English"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AdjustChapters^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetMode^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetInterleave^(1,500,1,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetClipMode^(1,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetConversion^(0,0,0,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetVolume^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetCompression^(85,48000,2,0,16000,1,12,"AQAEAAAAgAEBAAAA"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].EnableFilterGraph^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ) else (
      rem PROCESS MP3
      if !Mode_#0! equ Constant (
         rem JUST REMUX AUDIO
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetSource^(0x73647561,1,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].DeleteComments^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AddComment^(0x00000003,"","English"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AdjustChapters^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetMode^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetInterleave^(1,500,1,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetClipMode^(1,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetConversion^(0,0,0,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetVolume^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetCompression^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].EnableFilterGraph^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
      ) else (
         rem REDO AUDIO
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetSource^(0x73647561,1,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].DeleteComments^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AddComment^(0x00000003,"","English"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].AdjustChapters^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetMode^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetInterleave^(1,500,1,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetClipMode^(1,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetConversion^(0,0,0,0,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetVolume^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].SetCompression^(85,48000,2,0,16000,1,12,"AQAEAAAAgAEBAAAA"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         if !Sample_#0! equ 44100 (
            rem REDO 44100 AUDIO
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].EnableFilterGraph^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Add^("input"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Add^("resample"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Connect^(0, 0, 1, 0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.instance[1].SetInt^(0, 48000^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.instance[1].SetInt^(1, 64^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Add^("output"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Connect^(1, 0, 2, 0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         ) else (
            rem REDO 48000 AUDIO
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].EnableFilterGraph^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
            ECHO VirtualDub.stream[1].filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
         )
      )
   )
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.DeleteComments^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.AddComment^(0x00000002,"ISFT","VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2542/release)"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.AdjustChapters^(1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetDepth^(24,24^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetMode^(0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetFrameRate^(0,1^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetIVTC^(0,0,-1,0^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.SetCompression^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.video.filters.Clear^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.SaveAVI^("s:\\!NAMEFILE!.avi"^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   ECHO VirtualDub.Close^(^);>>"!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   "C:\VirtualDubMod\VirtualDubMod.exe" /r /s"R:\!NAMEFILE!.vcf" /x
   rem del "!NAMEFILE!.vcf"
   del "!NAMEFILE!.cod"
   rem del "!NAMEFILE!.audio1.wav"
   rem del "!NAMEFILE!.audio2.wav"
)
rem go back to original folder and delete the virtual drives.
%ORIGINALDRIVE%
subst r: /d
subst s: /d
```